# Eclipse referring old class files of Maven. Have to re-build the project everytime I make a single change

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-mars

I am using Maven projects in my `Eclipse` workspace.
But, somehow `Eclipse` is referring the old `.class` files while running the program.
Hence, I have to re-build the complete project everytime I make any change to any `java` program.

I have tried executing maven commands like `eclipse:clean` & `eclipse:eclipse`.
But, they did not help.
My eclipse is also set to `project - build automatically`.

Is there a way I can tell `Eclipse` to refer to the current built `.class` files and not the previously built maven `.class` files.

Note: I am using Eclipse Mars
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clean isn't removing all old class files?

Comment: Thing is, I have `build automatically` enabled, but when I select `Build Project / build all projects` Eclipse is not building any project. Only when I do a `Maven` build, it rebuilds the complete project.

Comment: Due to this, if I do a `eclipse clean project`, and then try to run the project, I get a `Could not find or load main class` Error.

Comment: Are you using M2Eclipse?

Comment: @Peter: No, I am using Eclipse Mars, and Maven is already integrated into Mars by default. Is M2Eclipse a different version ? And how is going to be helpful?

Comment: M2Eclipse or m2e is the maven plugin for eclipse, but it seems to be delivered with nearly every eclipse distribution. Could you explain your project setup in more detail? Do you have a single module? What do you mean by old `.class` files? Does eclipse build into a different directory than maven does? What kind of changes to the java program causes the issue?

Comment: @Peter: There are several modules which are interdependent on each other. 1) By old `.class` files I mean class files created by maven; since my `auto build` in eclipse is not working on maven projects. `--->` If I perform `eclipse clean build on the project` the `.class` files are deleted but not generated again when i do `eclipse build / build all`. Only when I perform `maven clean install`; thats when those `.class` files are re-created.  2) The directory of the `.class` files are the same for both maven as well as eclipse.  3) Any type of changes. e.g. writing a printf stmnt.

Comment: @AnirbanDebnath Did you find solution for this? I'm also having same issue.

Comment: @SyedMohammedMehdi: Sometimes the .project file of Eclipse gets corrupted.
Easy solution is :
1. Delete the project from Eclipse.
2. Close Eclipse.
3. Go to your project's folder and delete ".settings, .project, .classpath, bin" 
4. Open Eclipse again, and import your project once again.
This way it always works.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid. There is no way to doing it automatically. Even if you find a way to do so. There isn't any guarantee that eclipse will build with new war.

Either you go for manual mvn clean install or use intellij idea it is very much statble. No build issue. Every time on your single save it will build new war file.

Comment: This is strange. There should be atleast some way this issue can be sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to my question:

Sometimes the .project file of Eclipse gets corrupted. Easy solution is :

1. Delete the project from Eclipse.
2. Close Eclipse.
3. Go to your project's folder and delete ".settings, .project, .classpath, bin"
4. Open Eclipse again, and import your project once again.

This way it always works.